# Javascript For loop VS JQuery Each: strange result

Tags: javascript, performance

I've read several questions / articles about this subject and I tested in my solution that the same block of code using `for` is most of the times faster than `each`.

However my question is related to the fact than in my page where I've around 30 "loops" the starting results using `each` were around 5300ms (average) with max value of 5900ms and minimum of 4800ms.

And after I've changed them to `for` and the end result surprisingly is slower, takes more time as the previous average (and never got lower than 4800ms and got even higher than 6000ms)..... but when I place `console.time('Time')` `console.timeEnd('Time')` in each single "loop block" I get the expected result (FOR is faster).

***How is it possible that the global "time" is SLOWER using `for` than `each`?***

### *Could please you point me some possible reasons?*

**P.S.-** The full source-code is huge and the important part here is that the only change is:   loops `each` converted to `for`.

Sample used for the For loop

```
var l = list.length;  
for (var i=0;i<l; i++) {  

}
```

Sample used for the Each loop

```
$.each(list, function (i, item) {

});
```

**Update #1**

- Times are measured using `console.time('Time')`
  `console.timeEnd('Time')`. For global time I just use one "counter". For multiple counters I use different names of course.
- During all this "process" there are no Ajax requests, so the time different isn't connected to this.

**Update #2**

- As @epascarello requested: the "inner code" of each loop was never changed and it should not be the reason, even more when we access this objects the same way  (using `For` or `Each` ) `list[i].SomeProperty`, imho the time differences could never be blamed to the inner code (I think).

**Update #3**

- Sometimes I am using Cascading "loops" using different variables `i`, `ii`, `iii`.
- I often "reuse" variables inside the same function:

`var l = list1.length; ...; l = list2.length;`

The same applies to the `for` variables  `i`, `ii`, `iii`.

**Update #4**

I notice a strange behavior in Chrome: the following pattern uses to repeat several times, going down for a while and then spikes up again.

- DrawGUI: 6159.000ms ***UP AGAIN***
- DrawGUI: 5990.000ms ***going down***
- DrawGUI: 5804.000ms ***going down***
- DrawGUI: 5416.000ms ***going down***
- DrawGUI: 5315.000ms ***going down***
- DrawGUI: 5311.000ms ***going down***
- DrawGUI: 5325.000ms
- DrawGUI: 5248.000ms ***going down***
- DrawGUI: 5010.000ms ***going down***
- DrawGUI: 4886.000ms ***going down***
- DrawGUI: 5645.000ms ***UP AGAIN ***
- DrawGUI: 5247.000ms
- DrawGUI: 5446.000ms

During all this testes I close all the other chrome tabs and unnecessary applications. Trying to minimize unstable CPU availability.

Comment: Can you build a significative sample and put it on jsperf ? Vague performance discussion without code lead to nothing.

Comment: When you say "each" I take it your referring to `$.each`?

Comment: @dystroy sorry, not possible since I'm using Ajax/Json calls for "localhost" DBs and refactoring for a "public version" isn't an option  for now.

Comment: @James question updated.

Comment: You are missing the key part of the equation, what is being done in the loop? Also [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/)

Comment: @epascarello question updated

Comment: Wrap your for-loop in an IIFE, because one key difference is that the for loop does **not** introduce a new scope and thus it **does** matter what's inside the loop.

Comment: Make a [JSPerf.com](http://jsperf.com) Test and see how it runs over a large set.

Comment: According to the results from [this](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/125) test case, `for` is consistently more efficient than `$.each` - by a pretty big margin.

Comment: @james that is not in question here, I even tested and validated that, it is true. I can even point you other page telling the same: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/ "Use For Instead of Each" see the source code and results. My problem is not a "single" loop, but the global time of all the loops. This is the strange part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are benchmarking empty loops you give the JIT (just in time compiler) plenty of room for optimizations. It might be the case that the `each` call is removed all together as it has no side effects. The for loop however must run as the `i` is defined in the scope *containing* the for loop and not inside the for loop.

```
(function() {
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {}
    console.log(i); // outputs 10
})();
```

vs

```
(function() {
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].forEach(function(i) {});
    console.log(i); // i is not declared
})();
```

That is also the reasons why JSLint/JSHint complains about `i` being declared twice for the following code:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {}
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {}
```

Comment: I've run "blocks" of the code on JSLint/JSHint and one error that occurred several times was: "'i' is already defined." This means that I should not "reuse" variables? Could you please explain a little bit more your answer. Thanks.

Comment: You can reuse variables, but you should only use `var` once per scope. Thus in my example the second `for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {}` would simple need to drop the `var` in order to be JSLint/JSHint clean. It is as simple as that: Variables declared inside the `()` are *NOT* part of the for-loop but live in the outer scope. If you want to know more about scoping I suggest that you start a new question.